# Error in while : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, error-handling, while-loop

I am new in R and I am stuck in a silly error.. Although I found some questions that tackle my problem I can't solve it.

```
ww <- waveMC_list[[5]]
sampling=44100
thresh=10

timer.output <- timer(ww, f=sampling, threshold=thresh,envt="abs",ksmooth=kernel("daniell",100))


i=0
min.length=0.05                    # minimum length of segment
segmts=length(timer.output[[4]])   # total amount of segments to evaluate
segments <- list()                 # output of valid segments
starts=timer.output[[4]]           # starting times
ends=timer.output[[5]]             # ending times



for(i in 1:segmts)
{
  if(i <= segmts)
  {
  while(starts[i] <= ends[i]) #print(TRUE)
    {
    if((ends[i]-starts[i])>min.length)
      {
       segments[[i]] <- env(WaveMC(cutw(ww, f=44100, from= starts[i], to=ends[i],plot=F), bit= 16, samp.rate=44100)
                            , f=44100, ksmooth=kernel("daniell",90),plot=F)
       print(paste('check', i, sep=' '))
       print(segmts)
          #env("ACAWAVEFILE", f=44100, ksmooth=kernel("daniell",90)) 
      }   
       i=i+1
    }
  }
}

Error in while (starts[i] <= ends[i]) { :
```

missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the `if` condition evaluates to `NA`. This happens when either of the operands was `NA`. Check your input vectors for the values they contain.

---

Old reply, still relevant but results in a different error message:

The error means that your `if` condition is an empty vector. Why is it empty? Well, because of this part:

```
(ends[i]-starts[i])
```

Both `ends` and `starts` are a *single* element:

```
starts=timer.output[[4]]           # starting times
ends=timer.output[[5]]             # ending times
```

So of course `ends[i]` and `starts[i]` will only return an element for `i==1` and an empty vector for any other value.

Comment: Any clue in how could I avoid it?

Comment: already solved it! thanks!

Comment: Not empty, but NA. See the error messages of `while(c()) print("hi")` and `while(NA) print("hi")` are different. One of his `starts[i]` or `ends[i]` must be `NA`.

Comment: @flodel Nice catch. I’ll leave my old reply standing because it’s also a common error.